# Where is the error ???? KeyError: 'start_date'

Tags: python, django

I havent put any body arguments (start_date, end_date) in my GET request , should work else statement but appears strange mistake , so there is issue ??

```
class MoviesTop(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        if request.data.get('start_date', 'end_date'):
            start_timestamp = request.data['start_date']
            end_timestamp = request.data['end_date']
            topMovie = Movie.objects.annotate(
                num_comments=Count(
                    'Comments',
                    filter=Q(Comments__pub_date__range=(
                        start_timestamp, end_timestamp))
                )
                ).order_by('-num_comments')
            
        
        else:
            topMovie=Movie.objects.annotate(
                num_comments=Count('Comments')).order_by('-num_comments')
        
        
        serializer=MoviesTopSerializator(topMovie, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: Because `request.data` has no key `start_date`.

Comment: Notice that `request.data.get('start_date', 'end_date')` will have truthiness `True`, since even if `start_date` does not exists, it will return `'end_date'`, the second parameter is the *default* value, not another key that will be checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.data.get('start_date', 'end_date')` will have truthiness `True`, even if `start_date` does not exists. It will return `'end_date'`, the second parameter is the *default* value, not another key that will be checked.

You thus check this with:

```
if 'start_date' in request.data and 'end_date' in request.data:
    # …
```